# Table View Cells Double When I Add A New Cell - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am currently making a golf round tracker that displays your rounds in a table view with the cells being xibs. When I add one round, it appears fine on the table view, but when I add another round it adds that cell and doubles the cells. Here is a picture of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOgN4.png. Here is my code:

```
class RoundDisplay: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrayOfCellData.append(roundData(id : arrayOfCellData.count + 1, date : datePlayedFC, course : currentCourse, score : String(score1234) ))

        tableView.reloadData()

        print(arrayOfCellData)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //Shows how many cells it should display; number of current cells
        return arrayOfCellData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Shows how many cells it should display; number of current cells
       return arrayOfCellData.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            //Defines what xib to use for cells
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell



            //Adds array data to each cell
            cell.DateLbl.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].date
            cell.CourseName.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].course
            cell.ScoreLbl.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].score

            return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //Shows how high to make cells; height of xib
        return 68
    }
}
```

Comment: Your numberOfSections function should return 1.

Comment: You’ve implemented numberOfSections incorrectly. Try returning 1.

Comment: @Magnas Thank you very much that fixed my problem!

Comment: @RenderResults delete the `numberOfSections` method, default returning value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The number of sections function needs to be set to one. I realized that it decided how many cells it should show for the data from the array. Which means if you have the function set as I did, for instance, if you had two sets of data in the array, it would put two cells for each data. Thanks to @Magnas and @vacawama for the help!